# Elastic, Term (or _ID) query with Hyphen in value

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, hyphenation

I am struggling to query for exact match. This field is identical in two fields in the document, within `_id` and within one field in the body.

So I can search either of these fields. Is there any way to configure the term query to support this? I've tried specifying whitespace analyzer but it doesn't seem to be a supported configuration for term queries.

Ive tried a few variations, but none of it has worked so far..

```
data: {
    query: {
        term: {
            "_id":"4123-0000"            
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't return anything.

Comment: can you share your mapping, sample and expected docs ?

Comment: I dont think we have any special mapping. Everything is just plan-text, flat string fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that as you are using default mapping, your `_id` field seems to be populated by you, which would have used `text` field which uses the `standard` analyzer and splits the tokens based on `-`, so your `_id` field is tokenized as below:

POST /_analyze

```
{
  "text" : "4123-0000",
  "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

**And tokens**

```
 {
        "tokens": [
            {
                "token": "4123",
                "start_offset": 0,
                "end_offset": 4,
                "type": "<NUM>",
                "position": 0
            },
            {
                "token": "0000",
                "start_offset": 5,
                "end_offset": 9,
                "type": "<NUM>",
                "position": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now as you might be aware of that `term` query is not analyzed ie it uses the `4123-0000` as it is and tried to find in the inverted index, which is not available hence you don't get any result.

**Solution**, simply replace `_id` to `_id.keyword` to get the search result.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked! _id is the document ID added by logstash/elastic. But luckily, we have another field (added by us) that contains the same value. Adding .keyword on that worked!

Comment: @AllenH.  glad it was helpful and yeah you were lucky in this case, otherwise you would have to reindex everything again